# Bootstrap4.1 Navbar Vertical items instead of Horizontal Album Example

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am using 'Album' example from Bootstrap 4.1 and unable to get the extra nav-items to display horizontally.

[image: I added some nav-items and displays as vertical. How can I make it horizontal.]

I tried to add 'navbar-expand-lg', and it brings all to horizontal line. But, the toggler-button (and hence its header data) vanishes and becomes inaccessible.

Code as below;

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header>

      <!-- Navbar#1 Toggled - Detailed Header Info-->
      <div class="collapse bg-dark" id="navbarHeader">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 py-4">
              <h4 class="text-white">About</h4>
              <p class="text-muted">Lines of Data Shortened.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 offset-md-1 py-4">
              <h4 class="text-white">Contact</h4>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Follow on Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Like on Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Email me</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Navbar#2 Permanent Strip of Navbar -->
      <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark shadow-sm">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
             <!-- SVG Album Icon  -->
            <strong>Album</strong>
          </a>


          <!-- Nav Items Manually added -->
          <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </div>

          <!-- Navbar#3 - Visible Toggle Button -->
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

The navbar was a flexbox with 'd-flex'. So, I added a 'flex-row', which brings nav-items horizontally. 'mr-auto' brings margin properly.

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header>

      <!-- Navbar#1 Toggled - Detailed Header Info-->
      <div class="collapse bg-dark" id="navbarHeader">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 py-4">
              <h4 class="text-white">About</h4>
              <p class="text-muted">Lines of Data Shortened.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 offset-md-1 py-4">
              <h4 class="text-white">Contact</h4>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Follow on Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Like on Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Email me</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Navbar#2 Permanent Strip of Navbar -->
      <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark shadow-sm">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
             <!-- SVG Album Icon  -->
            <strong>Album</strong>
          </a>


          <!-- Nav Items Manually added -->
          <div class="navbar-nav flex-row mr-auto">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </div>

          <!-- Navbar#3 - Visible Toggle Button -->
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left;`CSS to your `li` items.
Also you can try this 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar&stacked=h

Comment: This will not work. It's not about float, as its already aligned left. The issue is with 'nav-item'.

Comment: @Abz I copy and past your code in the link that I mention in the answer and it is inline, Please try on your side

Comment: @Abz Do you have it online to I check it

Comment: I attached a code-snippet to try the issue. I solved the issue, as this was a flexbox issue. The nav-items changed to horizontal view by adding flex-row(row direction) property.

Comment: Then you can answer to your question and close it.